# HTTP/1.1 vs HTTP/1.0 Python socket

Tags: python, sockets, http

I am trying to send and receive `HTTP` data using the Python socket. But when I use `HTTP/1.0` it works but when I use `HTTP/1.1` it just keeps waiting...

*This code works*

```py
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('httpbin.org', 80)
client_socket.connect(server_address)

request_header = 'GET /ip HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\n\r\n'
client_socket.send(request_header.encode())

response = ''
while True:
    recv = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not recv:
        break
    response += recv 

print(response)
client_socket.close()
```

*This doesn't work*

```py
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('httpbin.org', 80)
client_socket.connect(server_address)

request_header = 'GET /ip HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\n\r\n'
client_socket.send(request_header.encode())

response = ''
while True:
    recv = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not recv:
        break
    response += recv 

print(response)
client_socket.close()
```

If the `HTTP/1.1` is the problem then how could I detect if it doesn't support  `HTTP/1.1`?

Comment: Why are you doing this with sockets instead of using a library like `urllib2`? HTTP is not a simple protocol, there are lots of details you need to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP/1.1 defaults to persistent connections. If you want the server to close the connection after it sends the response, you need to send the `Connection: close` header.

```
request_header = 'GET /ip HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
```